# Why does my integer object automatically convert to string after post method?

Tags: javascript

I have an object which converts my numbers into strings. I have done quite a bit of googling trying to figure why this occurs but am still unsure - I think it might have to do with JSON or header info in post method? So, my next attempt is to convert the object back to an integer. I saw couple options: parseInt(), Number(), split('""') but hasn't resolved my issue.

After Post:
    $rootScope.fullDay = {
        mon:"1",
        tue:"2"}

I need it to be in the following format: 
Before Post:

$rootScope.fullDay = {
        mon: 1,
        tue: 2 }

EDIT: The values are not in quotes as shown below:

```
 <li class="col-md-3">
     <input type="checkbox" id="Monday" ng-true-value= 1 ng-model="day.mon" ng-change="selectedDay()">
   <label class="ui-checkbox" for="Monday">Monday</label>
</li>                                            

 <li class="col-md-3">
     <input type="checkbox" id="Tuesday" ng-true-value= 2 ng-model="day.tue" ng-change="selectedDay()">
    <label class="ui-checkbox" for="Tuesday">Tuesday</label>
```

JS file:

```
$scope.selectedDay = function () {
    if (!$rootScope.edit) {
    console.log($scope.day) 
      $rootScope.fullDay = $scope.day;                 
      $rootScope.day = Object.keys($scope.day).map(key => $scope.day[key]);
      $rootScope.day.forEach(function (item, index) {
        if (item === false) {
          $rootScope.day.splice(index, 1);
        }
      });
      $rootScope.dayFormatted = $rootScope.day.join(' ');          
      $rootScope.schedule.weekdays.day['@'].day = $rootScope.dayFormatted;
    }
```

POST (only including partial):

```
 createJob_API: function () {
            var data = $.param({"fullDay": $rootScope.fullDay, "fullDate": $rootScope.fullDate})
     var settings = {
                method: 'POST',
                data: data,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' },
```

Here is an image of console log before POST:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yl9d.jpg
After:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgB27.jpg
Note: the second img is just an example of output not the same days selected as the before image.

Thanks for your help - I would appreciate if someone can tell me why the conversion happens automatically.

Comment: Can u show as how you POST this data, and how POST method handler looks?

Comment: don't use quotes if you want numbers - you're CREATING a string

Comment: `I need it to be in the following format` - then do that ... I'm beginning to suspect that piece of code isn't actual code

Comment: I am not adding quotes. That is the result after posting

Comment: @Heather OK, then, show us how you do that and how are you returning the data. Most likely, the data just gets returned _with_ quotes, which will make the object have strings, instead of numbers. I don't think I know of any "normal" way for data to accidentally switch its format after transmission. If there was, we'd be having a much harder time with using JSON.

Comment: The output you added where did u get it from? Is it the client or the server ? Can u please share `console.log ()` output of the object at client?

Comment: The values are strings. The value of an input/any HTML attribute  is always a type of string, no matter, if a number was entered/assigned to the attribute.

Comment: I am adding more details to the post...in few mins.

Comment: @MatjažMav: I have added the POST info to my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue with the following:

```
Object.keys($rootScope.edit.fullDay).forEach(function(key,value){
      $rootScope.edit.fullDay[key] = parseInt($rootScope.edit.fullDay[key]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` only supports key=value pairs. It doesn't distinguish between different data types. It supports only strings.

(A non-standard extension for it uses `[]` characters in the key name to represent arrays and objects, but there is nothing which distinguishes between strings and numbers).

If you want a number, then you'll have to convert the data to that format once it arrives on the server.

Comment: So you're saying I need to convert it back to an integer after the POST method? If so, do you know how I would be able to do that as I've already tried different options stated in the original question.

Comment: `foo = parseInt(foo, 10)` is traditional. `foo = +foo` if you just want it to be a number. You said you used `parseInt`, but it isn't clear how (your didn't provide an [mcve]) so it's unclear why it failed for you.

Comment: I'm sorry: I'm still fairly new to coding I tried the following, so not sure if this is correct: parseInt($rootScope.fullDay)

Comment: Will try with what you've provided

Comment: @Heather — `foo` should be the string containing the number, and you should call it for *each* string. It shouldn't be the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing them as a string by putting them in the quotes, if you'd store them like this:

```
var obj = {
  mon: 1,
  tue: 2
};
```

You will find that obj.mon is an int, not a string.